# Firebase user login authentication in Android shows an error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth to let user register and login, the registration login works fine as I checked through the Firebase assistant but the part does't works fine as on running this on my device after inserting the details it shows these errors in log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.shubham.presentsir, PID: 9679
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4855)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20280)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4855) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20280) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbo.zzcF(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.shubham.presentsir.Login.gotoDashboard(Login.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4855) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20280) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

and also assume that my manifest works fine as I have checked it.

```
private EditText email,pass;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private String email1,pass1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    setContentView( R.layout.activity_login );
    email=findViewById( R.id.editText5 );
    pass=findViewById( R.id.editText6 );
    email1=email.getText().toString();
    pass1=pass.getText().toString();
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

public void gotoDashboard(View view) {
//                progressDialog.setMessage( "Fetching your data" );
//              progressDialog.show();
//Error occured from here as it showing the error from this line of code can you help me from where I have did this wrong

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword( email1,pass1 )
            .addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>(){
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        startActivity( new Intent( Login.this,Dashboard.class ) );
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText( Login.this, ""e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    }

                }
            } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be passing `null` or an empty string to `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, so either `email1` or `pass1` doesn't have a value. Check their value before calling `signInWithEmailAndPassword`:

```
public void gotoDashboard(View view) {
  if (email1 != null && !email1.isEmpty() && pass1 != null && !pass1.isEmpty()) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword( email1,pass1 )
         .addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>(){
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    startActivity( new Intent( Login.this,Dashboard.class ) );
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText( Login.this, ""e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }

            }
         });
  }
}
```

This is really just a quick fix though. You should figure out why `email1` and `pass1` have no value, and prevent triggering `gotoDashboard` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not taking edittext values of `email` and `password` inside `gotToDashboard()` which is triggered on Button Click and hence sending null values of `email1` and `pass1`.  Do like this

```
public void gotoDashboard(View view)
{
    email1=email.getText().toString();
    pass1=pass.getText().toString();
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (email1 != null && !email1.isEmpty() && pass1 != null && !pass1.isEmpty())
    {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email1, pass1)
          .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Dashboard.class));
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, ""e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```